# How to hide show AlertDialog flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using showAlertDialog to alert the user to sign in with the following code:

```
  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context){
    AlertDialog alert=AlertDialog(
      content: new Row(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),child:Text("Loading" )),
        ],),
    );
    showDialog(barrierDismissible: false,
      context:context,
      builder:(BuildContext context){
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
```

And through the next line of code I run and show it to the user:

```
showAlertDialog(context);
```

The problem now: I am trying to stop or hide its work through the following line of code, but the matter does not work, I cannot hide it.

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
```

Is there a solution for that? I need to stop it and hide it.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```